# Boost.Fusion Functional: Calling functions with default arguments

Tags: c++, function, metaprogramming, function-pointers, boost-fusion

Is it possible to use [boost::fusion::invoke](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/functional/invocation/functions/invoke.html) function to call a function that has default arguments without specifying those?

```
Example:

void foo(int x, int y = 1, int z = 2)
{
  std::cout << "The sum is: " << (x + y + z) << std::endl;
}

...

// This should call foo(0). It doesn't work because the type of foo is void (*) (int, int, int).
boost::fusion::invoke(foo, boost::fusion::vector<int>(0));

// Works
boost::fusion::invoke(foo, boost::fusion::vector<int, int, int>(0, 1, 2));
```

I am writing a wrapper for bindings to a scripting language and default arguments would greatly improve the intuitive feel for the users of the wrapper. I am afraid though that the standard has not covered this case.

**A side note:**
I know one could work around it using functors:

```
struct foo  {
  void operator() (int x, int y = 1, int z = 2)  { /* ... */ }
};

// Works because the functor adds an indirection
boost::fusion::invoke(foo(), boost::fusion::vector<int>(0));
```

This is however not an option as I don't want to force the users to create functors just to specify default arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind` ([more info](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bind/bind.html)):

```
boost::fusion::invoke(boost::bind(foo, _1, 1, 2), boost::fusion::vector<int>(0));
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a reasonable solution. I was more interested in specifying the default arguments directly in the function declaration but it seems that it's simply impossible to combine those with invoke().